# mapbox gl js absolute label size

Tags: text, label, mapbox-gl-js

I'm looking for a way to create relative size text-labels using mapbox-gl js. My goal is to create a label that will always have the same size relative to the map (so the label would actually get bigger when you zoom in).

Is there any way that this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this behaviour currently is to use a [zoom function](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#types-function) whose output grows in powers of 2 ([example](http://jsbin.com/sapevenece/edit?html,output))